What side effect does this jackson serialization unit test have?
When I run these unit tests, validateNotRequired fails at the line assertFalse(jsonNode.has("id")); If I change the order of execution of the two unit tests, both pass. What side effect does the validateRequired unit test have, that could cause this?
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.json.JsonSchema;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.everit.json.schema.ValidationException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class CustomKafkaJsonSchemaSerializerOrderTest {
    @Test
    @Order(0)
    void validateNotRequired() throws JsonProcessingException {
        JsonSchema schema = new JsonSchema("""
                {
                  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/B",
                  "definitions": {
                    "B": {
                      "title": "B",
                      "properties": {
                        "id": {
                          "type": "string"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                """);
        try (var serializer = new KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer<Y>()) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = serializer.objectMapper();
            objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT);
            JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.convertValue(new Y(), JsonNode.class);
            assertFalse(jsonNode.has("id"));
            schema.validate(jsonNode);
        }
    }

    @Test
    @Order(-1)
    void validateRequired() {
        JsonSchema schema = new JsonSchema("""
                {
                  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/B",
                  "definitions": {
                    "B": {
                      "title": "B",
                      "required": [
                        "id"
                      ],
                      "properties": {
                        "id": {
                          "type": "string"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                """);
        try (var serializer = new KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer<Y>()) {
            JsonNode jsonNode = serializer.objectMapper()
                    .convertValue(new Y(), JsonNode.class);
            assertThrows(ValidationException.class, () -> schema.validate(jsonNode));
        }
    }

    @Getter
    private static class Y {
        private String id;
    }
}

